# how exactly does the c preprocessor apply constants and macro substitutions?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm getting realy confused with the c preprocessor that comes with GCC. Consider the following code:
//mleak_cpp.h

```
#ifndef _NO_LEAK_
#define malloc(x) __malloc_debug(__FILE__,__LINE__,x);
```

the "_NO_LEAK_" constant really just makes sure that the implementation of __malloc_debug, which uses normal malloc, doesn't get processed and become a recursive function.

//mleak_cpp.cpp

```
//on top
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define _NO_LEAK_
#include <stdlib.h>
//...rest of the code
//which included __malloc_debug implementation that calls malloc()
```

This works alright, with the malloc inside __malloc_debug left at is, which is what I wanted. For some reason, putting the "stdlib.h" line on top of "#define _NO_LEAK_" causes a seg-fault. After examining the preprocessor output, apparently the malloc call inside __malloc_debug was replaced by the macro.

So what is the mechanism that causes this behaviour? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Seems strange.  If you're using GCC, you might run the code through "gcc -E" or "g++ -E" and see what changes with `<stdlib>` above or below that line.

Comment: C or C++ ? They're very similar in the preprocessing phase, but let's not mix the two.

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_NO_LEAK_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation (the compiler and its library). Don't use them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is to localized due to the usage of a custom version of stdlib.h

Comment: @bummi I plead not guilty as I didn't know that was the case

Comment: Oh sorry, this is not against you and not a question of guilty, but of questionable usefulness for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting your time guys, but I've found the cause of the error. The company I'm working for is using a custom version of stdlib.h, which includes mleak_cpp.h at the end, which is what causes the behaviour. Changing the name of the constant or changing the order of the preprocessor directives therefore makes a difference.
Who'd have seen that coming.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor actually just does a substitution of text before the compilation phase starts. It does no more than this.

If you want to see what the preprocessor does then you can instruct gcc to just preprocess the file then stop at that point in time. The command to do that is:

`g++ -E myfile.cpp`

Perhaps see the difference in the code between putting the `#define _NO_LEAK_` before `#include <stdlib.h>` vs afterwards.

```
#ifndef _NO_LEAK_
#define malloc(x) __malloc_debug(__FILE__,__LINE__,x);
```

This snippet of code just does the substitution for `malloc(x)` only if `_NO_LEAK` is not defined.

Comment: I did just that except within an IDE. The preprocessor actually applies the macro when "stdlib.h" is above "_NO_LEAK_"

Comment: @user3109672 Can you search stdlib.h and see if there's a line `#define _NO_LEAK_` in there?

Comment: well in that case... ahem, I did paraphrase the name of the constant. I'll try if changing its name helps.